# StackExchange.Redis Extremely Slow

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am evaluating some options to replace System.Web.Caching.Cache with a caching system that could be shared across a web farm. I'm currently evaluating redis but it is extremely slow. Given that redis is well regarded and I have the redis instance hosted on the same server as the web server that is calling it I figure there is something that i'm missing with my implementation. Here is my connection manager:

```
    Public Class RedisConnection

    Private Shared lazyConnection As New Lazy(Of ConnectionMultiplexer)(Function()
                                                                            Return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Redis").ConnectionString)
                                                                        End Function)

    Private Shared _database As IDatabase = lazyConnection.Value.GetDatabase()

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Connection() As ConnectionMultiplexer
        Get
            Return lazyConnection.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Database() As IDatabase
        Get
            Return _database
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Server() As IServer
        Get
            Dim endpoints As EndPoint() = Connection.GetEndPoints(True)
            Return Connection.GetServer(endpoints.First())
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

And here are my extensions: (I'm using jil for serialization ATM)

```
    Public Module RedisExtensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Function [Get](Of T)(ByVal cache As IDatabase, ByVal key As String) As T
        Return Deserialize(Of T)(cache.StringGet(key))
    End Function

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Sub [Set](ByVal cache As IDatabase, ByVal key As String, ByVal value As Object)
        cache.StringSet(key, Serialize(value))
    End Sub

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Sub [Set](ByVal cache As IDatabase, ByVal key As String, ByVal value As Object, ByVal expiration As DateTime)
        cache.StringSet(key, Serialize(value))
        cache.KeyExpire(key, expiration)
    End Sub

    Private Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal value As Byte()) As T
        If value Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Return JSON.Deserialize(Of T)(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value))
    End Function

    Private Function Serialize(ByVal value As Object) As Byte()
        If value Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSON.Serialize(value))
    End Function

End Module
```

Anything stand out as obviously wrong? Is introducing the serialization/serialization and network travel that much slower than System.Web.Caching.Cache?

Thanks!

Comment: `Caching.Cache` is inmemory cache of current process, so it will be always much faster than external cache storage. And the difference can be big. What numbers do you have? How much takes inmemory and redis ways? How big is difference between them?

Comment: It went from ~200ms. To 3-7 minutes to load the home page.

Comment: The difference is too big. Does Redis located on a different server? Maybe ping to server is also big and it causes problems? The best way to understand it to try to profile application with profiler. Like JetBrains dotTrace\etc. It can give more details. Maybe bottleneck is in json serializer...

Comment: How much data are you serializing? Have you tried ping to the server?

Comment: The cache is ~100MB in total across ~100 keys. I don't need to ping the server because the redis instance is running locally so there should be no network throughput issues.

Comment: So, you are serializing 100Mb of data as json and putting it to Redis? If this operation is done on each request, then it's a LOT of data....

Comment: 1Mb per key is probably too much, but you could try to GZip the serialized string before sending it thru the network, stackechange.redis also works with byte arrays.

Comment: Thanks to you all for helping. I looked into the cache size and there was an issue with my check to see if something exists, the cache is now down to 8MB. I also looked into the serialization/deserialization and there was indeed some slowdown from it that solved by memoizing deserialized objects within the httpcontext. It is still much too slow, but I am not ignoring the everyone's advice.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using your own implementation instead of the one that is mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798898.aspx.  Although this cache provider was written for Azure Redis, you should be able to use it against non-azure also...

Comment: Perhaps i'm misunderstanding the purpose of that package but it looks like it's used for output caching. I'm looking to cache arbitrary data rather than the actual html.